# While running sgx (software guarded extension) code than I got error as CPU not supported sgx

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, sgx

I have problem related sgx extension
My Intel processor version is intel core i5-6300U CPU @2.40Ghz 2.50Ghz

In Google when I search these above processor specification than in specs it shows that intel sgx is supported but while running utils/linux/test-sgx
It shows sgx available:0 and while running sgx related code than I got error as cpu not supported sgx

Comment: `sgx available:0` indicates you do not have sgx

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: check using [this tool](https://github.com/ayeks/SGX-hardware/blob/master/test-sgx.c) that your CPU actually supports SGX instruction set.

Step 2: check your BIOS, it's very likely that you need to enable SGX manually.

Comment: Where to run these code either in online c compiler

Comment: Compile and run it on the machine you want to test. See the repo's README file.